# php many elseif statements better performance

Tags: php

I was writing a Site in php the last few weeks and always had a question in my mind. On my index.php I route all the templates file like this

```
    if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        include_once 'template/template.search.php';
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['newsletter'])){
        include_once 'template/template.newsletter.php';
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['product'])){
        include_once 'template/template.product.php';
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['categories'])){
        include_once 'template/template.categorie.php';
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['about'])){
        include_once 'template/template.about.php';
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['sitemap'])){
        include_once 'template/template.sitemap.php';
    }
    else
    {   
        include_once 'template/template.index.php';     
    }
```

But for me it dosen't look very clean. Is there a better possibility to handle a job like this ?

I already tried it like this, but didn't worked out for me

```
    $i = 0 ;
    switch($i){
    case(isset($_GET['search'])):
        include_once 'template/template.search.php';
        break;
    default:
        include_once 'template/template.index.php'; 
        break;
}
```

Edit: Better writing in the title was a bit misleading some of you, so I'm searching for the best performance for sure.

Comment: `switch` statement would solve this

Comment: you could use `switch` http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Another option might be to look at routing with something like .htaccess

Comment: I meant not solve this, but might improve readability

Comment: There is nothing to switch on!

Comment: @ithcy You can switch on boolean `true` and make your cases `isset()`.

Comment: Well, sure. You *could* do a million different things. Just using `switch` doesn't automatically make your code more understandable!

Comment: you should do `$_GET['module']` then switch on module

Comment: @Asok: Really? So then what would your case statements be?

Comment: @ithcy you are spamming the crap out of this page with no answers or suggestions of your own. Are you trolling questions only to discredit those trying to help or are you actually planning on providing something constructive (like an actual answer) to the OP's Q. You seem to know the best solution but you choose not to contribute.

Comment: @Asok As opposed to your ridiculous suggestion (switch on the query string)? So then which answer below is yours?

Comment: @ithcy I agree my comment is ridiculous, it wasn't well thought out and I jumped-the-gun on contributing. Once realized, I stopped and upvoted the answer I believe is best. I didn't spam all of the other comments/answers. I'm just tired of the common dev attitude of "piss on you I'm the best and I refuse to help such trivial questions, but I'll undoubtedly spend my time telling you how much you suck at what I do."

Comment: @Asok I'm sorry your feelings got hurt. I was in the middle of typing up an answer, left my desk, and when I came back @acheong87 had already submitted a pretty much identical answer, which I upvoted. I offered a *real* suggestion to try to improve a particular answer, and then when @alfasin didn't understand my comment I attempted to clarify it. And I will just stick to my opinion that `switch` doesn't automatically make your code better, if you don't mind, that is.

Comment: @Asok by the way, feel free to take a look through my activity history if you think I'm just here to "piss on you" and "refuse to help". I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too much cleaner, but a [switch](http://php.net/switch) is the best thing to use for this. Readability is about 15,000% better.

```
switch(true) {
    case isset($_GET['search']):
        include_once 'template/template.search.php';
        break;

    // do more

    default:
        include_once 'template/template.index.php';
        break;
}
```

Comment: I disagree. In this specific case, the switch *reduces* readability.

Comment: I agree with itchy, and if I were the OP I would choose to accept @acheong87's answer!

Comment: Most of the answers here a reasonable, however I believe using a loop in such a manner assumes that the key of the get variable will match a part of the file name religiously. Since we try not to localize answers here on SO, I chose a form that would match another curious user's needs.

Comment: @phpisuber01 I would discard the switch *and* enforce consistency between page selector and actual page names especially thinking of a curious beginner wandering on this page. Code readability and minimal data redundency are two principles that you can't learn too soon, in my opinion.

Answer (score 11):

How about this?

```
$templates = array('search',
                   'newsletter',
                   'product',
                   'categories',
                   'about',
                   'sitemap',
                   'index');

foreach ($templates as $template)
{
    if (isset($_GET[$template]))
    {
        include_once "template/template.$template.php";
        break;
    }
}
```

You really should specify an array of valid templates—it's much safer.

I guess an alternative is to search the other way around:

```
$templates = array('search',
                   'newsletter',
                   'product',
                   'categories',
                   'about',
                   'sitemap',
                   'index');

foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
{
    if (in_array($key, $templates))
    {
        include_once "template/template.$key.php";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably want to add a `break` after `include_once`.

Comment: @alfasin - I actually didn't see your answer as I wrote mine, but a +1 deserved and returned to you nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `$_GET` holds only the `includes` you can do:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val){
    if(isset($key)){
        include_once 'template/template.'.$val.'.php';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if `$val` is an array?

Comment: @RPM I don't understand your question: `$_GET` is indeed an array

Comment: I meant what if `$val` is an array?

Comment: Also, his values are not ALWAYS in the file name. See 'categories' for example.

Comment: more importantly, what if more than one of the $_GET keys exist? Then all of those files will be included.

Comment: @RPM Oh, now I see you aditted your comment :) so in that case you can simple add: to the `isset` condition `&& ! (is_array($val))`

Comment: @phpisuber01 that could be easily fixed by renaming the file from `template.categorie.php` to `template.categories.php`

Comment: @itchy I don't understand your question, you mean that `$_GET['search']` will be set but that we shouldn't include `'template/template.search.php'` ?

Comment: This will work, but perhaps not if the query is `?newletter=newletter&foo=1`, where it try and include `template/template1.php` which won't exist

Comment: No, I mean if both `$_GET['search']` and `$_GET['newsletter']` exist (if the URL was `?search=1&newsletter=1`) , then your code would include both `template/template.search.php` and `template/template.newsletter.php`.

Comment: @Adam-E see my response to RPM's comment

Comment: @ithcy not it won't, because of the `break;` and regardless, if you pass both parameters what kind of behavior would you expect ? the OP doesn't state that he expects some kind of `precedence` - but if so, cheong87's improvement of my answer will do!

Comment: @alfasin yeah, you edited that in after I made my comment. Also, precedence is implied because OP is using XOR (elseif).

Comment: @ithcy you're right (about me adding that line - you can see that I edited my answer 5 mins ago while your 2nd comment was there 4 mins ago),  anyways, you had a good point which is now fixed ;)

Comment: @alfasin Bears love honey!

Answer (score 2):

Just a few passing thoughts...

- performance here is not an issue at all.
  Even a serie of `if`s withouth `else`s would be executed in a few microseconds.

Code maintenability and robustness *is* an issue, though.

I find the slightly hackish use of switch somewhat unsatisfactory or even dangerous, because

- the important information (the GET index and the actual page name) is still duplicated and burried in a glob of repetitive code,
- the switch will behave oddly if two conditions happen to be true simultaneously (I suppose it will take the first satisfied condition, but still that's not very clean)
- adding or removing a page still requires to duplicate/erase 3 or 4 lines of code, and inadvertently duplicating a block might go unnoticed and put the programmer in the annoying "I'm sure this matter was settled (but it actually wasn't)" situation.

As a matter of fact, I find the interface a bit strange. Passing a single "target" variable that would enumerate the possible pages seems more consistent to me. That would eliminate the odd cases where two page selection flags would be set simultaneously.

You can then have a simple list of targets and either compute the name of the target pages or have them stored in an assoc array (if you really can't name them in a consistent way, although I wonder what strange requirement would prevent you from doing that).

The key points I would consider for robustness are

- no data duplication
- no "lazy" default case (unless the default value comes from a functional requirement)

For all these reasons, I would change the way the page is selected, like so:

```
$pages = array (                  // single data source
    "search",
    "newsletter",
    // etc...
    );
@$page = $pages=[$_GET["page"]];  // single page selector
if (!$page) $page = "index";      // explicit default case

include "template/template.$page.php"; // no reason to include only once

// if someone else happens to include the template, better have the page
// break down immediately and correct the problem than letting a piece of
// buggy code live happily somewhere in your scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array: if you find the key inside, use it, otherwise just use default :

```
<?php
$tpl = array(
'search' => 'template/template.search.php',
'newsletter' => 'template/template.newsletter.php',
'product' => 'template/template.product.php'
#...
);

foreach($_GET as $get){
   if(array_key_exists($get, $tpl)) include_once($tpl[$get]); // assuming search is within $get
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable (like t) in the query string to indicate the template you want to use, and then just include the template name dynamically based on that. So if your URL looks something like: mysite.com/page.php?t=newsletter&blah=1&..., then all you need to do is:

```
include_once('template/template.' . $_GET['t'] . '.php');
```