# Optimistict way of programming rather than using if else

Tags: php, mysql

Whats is the best way of optimistic programming in the cases of multiple if else. Heard that usage of multiple if else decreases the programming performance.???

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284679/php-many-elseif-statements-better-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to take decision on the basic single value in this case switch case is very economic in comparison with if, else. suppose we have a variable $data can have various type of value then in this case use of switch case is very economic

```
switch($data){
    case  'username':
      // do the thing with username;
     break;
     case  'anotherdata':
      // do the thing with another data;
     break;
    // do the same 
   default:
   //do default thong   

}

if you want to use switch on different variable then you can also use
switch(true) {
    case isset($_GET['search']):
        include_once 'template/template.search.php';
        break;

    // do more

    default:
        //do your work
        break;
}
```

Hope it will help you....

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have several IF statements or ELSEIF statements... you can use a 'SWITCH' instead of IF and ELSEIF. see below.

```
if ($i == 0) {
  echo "i equals 0";
} elseif ($i == 1) {
  echo "i equals 1";
} elseif ($i == 2) {
  echo "i equals 2";
}elseif ($i == 3) {
  echo "i equals 3";
}
```

below is the replacment with switch :

```
switch ($i) {
case 0:
    echo "i equals 0";
    break;
case 1:
    echo "i equals 1";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "i equals 2";
    break;
case 3:
    echo "i equals 3";
    break;
}
```

The advantage of the above example is that if any one statement is satisfied the others will not run. They will break and the code will not continue to check the other conditions.
In the above example if $i == 0 the first statement will print and the rest wont be executed.